# Errors after moving redmine database from one server to a new installation

Tags: redmine, bitnami

I have a redmine instance running on windows (Bitnami Redmine). I've exported the database (a dump using mysqldump).

I have a new Ubuntu Server installed on another computer with another redmine instance (just installed).

I opened a phpmyadmin session on the new Ubuntu Server, made a backup of the new redmine database and then restored the backup from my original server.

I then logged into redmine using my original server user/pwd with no problems.
I can move through projects, and issues perfectly, However, every time I press the "New Issue" option, or Settings in a project the following error appears:

**Internal error
An error occurred on the page you were trying to access.
If you continue to experience problems please contact your Redmine administrator for assistance.
If you are the Redmine administrator, check your log files for details about the error.**

The same if I go to "My account" or Administration -> Users or Administration -> Issues statuses.

Also, if I try to edit an existing issue, when i hit the Save button, it explodes.

Comment: Does the old and the new Redmine instance have the same version? Have you done migrations?

Comment: The problem is versions, I saw different columns in both databases. How to migrate? Now I onloy have a .sql file from my original redmine

Comment: That's okay. Just populate the the new database with the data from the sql file and then execute the migrations of Redmine. Read [this](http://www.redmine.org/projects/redmine/wiki/RedmineUpgrade#Step-4-Update-the-database) for doing migrations (I recomment to read the complete page).